# How does the implementation of #doesNotUnderstand in the Object class result in opening a debugger in Squeak smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I know that the implementation signals a `MessageNotUnderstood` exception, but how does that end up opening a debugger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When an Exception remains unhandled after it has been signalled, its `#defaultAction` is invoked. MessageNotUnderstood>>defaultAction delegates to Error>>defaultAction, which signals an `UnhandledError` (another Exception). This exception, in turn, has a defaultAction whose code reads like this:

```
^ ToolSet debugError: self exception
```

...which opens the debugger if you use the StandardToolSet (which is the default in regular Squeak images).

Comment: I'm wondering what invokes #defaultAction? I suspect that it's invoked from `UndefinedObject>>handleSignal:` when there are no more exception handlers in the call chain. Is this true? Or, is the VM sending that message when no more handlers remain?

Comment: @rationalrevolt Yes, it's true. The VM isn't involved in the way exceptions are handled.